# element in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want make a feature that users can like comments similar instagram can like others posts.

```
<div *ngFor="let comment of comments | orderBy: '-'+orderBy">
  <div class="comment-item" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        {{comment.userName}}
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        {{comment.time | timeAgo}}
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="likeComment(comment._id)"
                        [@notliked]="notliked"></i>
       <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="unlikeComment(comment._id)"
                           [@liked]="liked"></i>
       {{comment.like}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <p class="comment-content">{{comment.textArea}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then I create two variable in component to control which icon should display.

```
notliked = 'open';
liked = 'close';
likeComment(commentId) {
    this.liked = 'open';
    this.notliked = 'close';
    this.dataService.likeComment(commentId).subscribe(
        res=>{

        },
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}

unlikeComment(commentId) {
    this.liked = 'close';
    this.notliked = 'open';
    this.dataService.unlikeComment(commentId).subscribe(
        res=>{

        },
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}
```

My problem is all my loop items by *ngFor changed in same time, and I hope just change selected one. I know I can't use global variable, but how to bind a property on elements separately created in *ngFor? thanks!

Comment: What are you doing with `comment._id` you're passing to `likeComment(...)` and `unlikeComment(...)`?

Comment: Sorry, I miss something and edit again. I post  comment._id to server then the feature alright:)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this without using any global variable, may help you

```
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true" (click)="likeComment(comment)"
                [@notliked]="comment?.liked"></i>
<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="unlikeComment(comment)"
                   [@liked]="!comment?.liked"></i>

 likeComment(commentId) {
    commentId.liked = true;
}

unlikeComment(commentId) {
    commentId.liked = false;
}
```

Comment: sorry i have no idea about `[@XYZ]` but syntax will be same as i posted

Comment: Thank you very much! [@XYZ] is animation I used, so it should be removed. I hope display one icon one time and in order to do this, think I have to add *ngIf . Unfortunately, I use your code still get error:
  Cannot create property 'liked' on string '58bcc8238ba8230f6cb8f5c2'
,but I believe it almost success.

Comment: thankuu so much to you too for information related to animation.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add one more key 'is_liked' into your array 'comments'. due to which we identify whether the comment is liked or disliked.

comments=[
  {is_liked:false}
]

in your method pass the index of the array and make that comment liked or disliked accordingly

```
likeComment(commentId,index) {
    comment[index].is_liked=true;
    this.liked = 'open';
    this.notliked = 'close';
    this.dataService.likeComment(commentId).subscribe(
        res=>{

        },
        error => console.log(error)
    )
}
```

to add key in your array object, run the loop like this

```
for(let i=0;i<comments.length;i++){
  comments[i].is_liked=false;
}
```

Comment: I think it will work, but how to assign comment=[ {is_liked:false} ] in comments array, thank you.